# Laravel 8 - The process has been signaled with signal "11" when self referencing relationships in factories

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

I am getting the following error 'The process has been signaled with signal "11".' when performing a self reference relationship inside my CategoryFactory.  For instance i have the following code:

CategoryTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\Models\Categories;

use App\Models\Category;
use Tests\TestCase;

class CategoryTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic unit test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_it_has_children()
    {
        $category = Category::factory()
            ->has(Category::factory()->count(3), 'children')
            ->create();

        $this->assertInstanceOf(Category::class, $category->children->first());
    }
}
```

Looks like here is where the error is coming from. I am now sure if this is the correct way to reference a hasMany relationship.

CategoryFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CategoryFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Category::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $name = $this->faker->unique()->name,
            'slug' => Str::of($name)->slug('-'),
            'parent_id' => Category::factory() // This seems to be causing the error
        ];
    }
}
```

Category.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'order'
    ];

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I have no clue what this error might be pointing to

Answer (score 1):

About the line, which as you think seems to be causing error.
I think the error could be caused by recursion or something like this.
Try to change it to:

```
'parent_id' => function () {
   return factory(Category::class)->create()->id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call `Category::factory()->create()`, it is internally creating a parent for it by calling `Category::factory()->create()` so this is an eternal loop.

Your child creation logic is fine, and they are getting the correct parent assigned.

You can solve this by assigning a null parent to the top-level category when using it

```
$category = Category::factory()
            ->has(Category::factory()->count(3), 'children')
            ->create(['parent_id' => null]);
```

It would be better if you change it in the factory so that the automatically created parent is a top-level category.

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'name' => $name = $this->faker->unique()->name,
        'slug' => Str::of($name)->slug('-'),
        'parent_id' => Category::factory(['parent_id' => null]) //Here
   ];
}
```

---

As a side note, your factory would behave in a weird way if you just provide the name argument. As the slug would be for a different name

```
//Currently
Category::factory()->create();
//Creates ['name' => 'Random Name', 'slug' => 'random-name']

Category::factory()->create(['name' => 'Johny Johnson']); 
//Creates ['name' => 'Johny Johnson', 'slug' => 'random-name-not-related-to-name']
```

```
//By changing this
public function definition()
{
    return [
            'name' => $this->faker->unique()->name,
            'slug' => fn($data) => Str::of($data['name'])->slug('-'), //Notice the function here
            'parent_id' => Category::factory(['parent_id' => null])
    ];
}


//With the change
Category::factory()->create();
//Creates ['name' => 'Random Name', 'slug' => 'random-name']

Category::factory()->create(['name' => 'Johny Johnson']); 
//Creates ['name' => 'Johny Johnson', 'slug' => 'johny-johnson']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the trait RefreshDatabase to my test class

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    

 }
```